# Unity - Light Flicker Script not running/working on Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I am very new to both C# and Unity, so I have been following some tutorials to create a Wall Torch (GameObject) that has a child 2D Spot Light which flickers using the following script I found on Github.
https://gist.github.com/sinbad/4a9ded6b00cf6063c36a4837b15df969
According to Visual Studio, the script has no errors.

However, upon hitting Play to start the script, nothing happens. There are no errors or messages in the Console.

[image: Example]

I have attached the script as a component to the 2D light, and made sure the class and script name are identical.

I have tried restarting the project and creating a new one, as well as deleting and recreating the script. The Unity project is 2D with URP.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Add debug logs in the script and see if those log messages are getting printed. If not, then script is probably not getting executed.

Comment: Please add debug log on the Start method and on the update method after the null check to see if something happen, if something happen so try to add break points and debug what happen

Comment: `Light2D` != `Light` => `GetComponent<Light>` will return `null` ... the script stupidly hides this with `if (light == null) return;` and makes the whole component silently fail .. one of the classic cases where you **WANT** to get an exception rather than hiding it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven´t tested this, but I think the problem is that the script tries to get a `Light` component from your GameObject, but you have a `Light2D` component. Try replacing the `public new Light light;` line in the script with `public Light2D light;`, and on line 45 change `Light` to `Light2D`, and it should work;

Comment: Thanks, that was a large part of the problem.
Also, as the original code was written for 3d, the new code must include 

    using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

and as such 

    float newVal = Random.Range(minIntensity, maxIntensity);

must be changed to 

    float newVal = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minIntensity, maxIntensity);

This then works perfectly.
I also posted a fork on the original script containing the updated code;

https://gist.github.com/lucasmhdev/b9593a07a9a3e72ea681fa3eb9ef0898.js

Thanks for your help!